# Слово “галстук” — літературне?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники

У **[СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghalstuk)** знайшла обидва варіанти:

> **ГА́ЛСТУК**, а, Стрічка, смужка тканини, яку пов'язують під коміром сорочки, блузи і т. ін. вузлом або бантом; краватка. Комірчики й сорочка, чорний блискучий галстук на шиї були засмальцьовані, аж блищали проти сонця (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 207);
>
> **КРАВА́ТКА**, и, Зав'язана вузлом під коміром сорочки, блузки смужка тканини, яку носять для прикраси. Йшли.. похмурі робітники, і їх суворість наче замикали чорні костюми аж до краваток з крепу (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 401)

Однак знаю, що ***в російській мові*** теж ***є*** слово ***галстук***. До сьогодні думала, що це запозичення, тому його ніколи не використовувала.

Отож чи нормативно вживати слова галстук і краватка, чи слід таки оминати перше, замінюючи другим?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово **галстук** знаходимо і в [СУМі у 20 т.](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17515) Також знаходимо **галстук** як синонім до [краватка](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA):

> **КРАВА́ТКА** (завʼязана вузлом під коміром сорочки, блузки смужка тканини, яку носять для прикраси), **ГА́ЛСТУК**, САМОВ’Я́З, МЕТЕ́ЛИК *розм.* (така прикраса у вигляді банта).

Слово [галстук](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=461)
запозичене з німецької мови, тому і не дивно, що воно наявне і в українській, і в російській мовах:

> **га́лстук** «краватка», [*гальшту́к*] «нашийник» Ба; — р. бр. *га́лстук*, п. halsztuk «краватка, нашийник»;
>
> запозичення з німецької мови; нім. Hálsstück «річ для шиї» утворене з основ іменників Hals «шия», спорідненого з двн. днн. гот. hals, дангд. heals, лат. collus (<colsus) «тс.», і Tuch «хустка», спорідненого з двн. tuoh, днн. дфриз. dōk, гол. doek, або Stück «кусок; штука».
>
> Шанский ЭСРЯ 1 4, 20; [Фасмер 1 389](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=/usr/local/share/starling/morpho&basename=morpho%5Cvasmer%5Cvasmer&text_word=%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA&method_word=substring); Hüttl-Worth 17; Kluge—Mitzka 284—285, 796; Walde—Hofm. 1 245.
>
> Див. *шту́ка*. Пор. *кольє́*.

Отже, **галстук** нормативно вживати в українській мові.

Comment: Поправте запjзичене -> запозичене, бо від мене вимагає 6 символів в зміні :)